# How to use a dynamice appbar for call other function Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm very new to flutter, so I couldn't figure it out. When a user customizes their ap[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prN2i.jpg)pbar setting in the App Ui menu setting, I implement a check box where they click on the icon they want and see the app bar. The icons appear how is possible.

Comment: share your code and where you want use a checkbox?

Comment: can you explain in brief and please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since on one screen the user selects desirable icons and it has to be transferred to next screen and through new launch of apps, you need to save it in local storage with the help of packages such as "SharedPreference" or "Hive". Here, I have used SharedPreference.

[image: Imageref]

Since, sharedPreference supports List only and not List, we need to map IconData as String to store when user selects the iconData and retrieve it to show in Appbar.
Use a map to and define a key for all icons that you use.

```
Map<String, IconData> iconsAsString = {
  "add": Icons.add,
  "delete": Icons.delete,
  "save": Icons.save,
  "settings": Icons.settings
};
```

You need to set these String keys when checkbox is true and remove the keys when checkbox is false for the corresponding icon.

Once the List has been set in SharedPref, we can extract icons from the keys and show icon accordingly in all screens throughout our app.

In case you need to remove all selectedIcons, remove it from SharedPreference list. I have commented the part of removal for now in "initState".

Please go through the code below.

```
Map<String, IconData> iconsAsString = {
  "add": Icons.add,
  "delete": Icons.delete,
  "save": Icons.save,
  "settings": Icons.settings
};

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  /// Uses SharedPref to get selected
  /// Uses iconsAsString Map to get IconData corresponding to saved String in SharedPref
  Future<List<IconData>> getSelectedIcons() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<IconData> iconDataList = [];
    List<String>? selectedIcons = pref.getStringList("selectedIcons");
    if (selectedIcons != null) {
      for (var iconString in selectedIcons) {
        iconDataList.add(iconsAsString[iconString]!);
      }
    }
    return iconDataList;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // clearSelectedIcons();
  }

  clearSelectedIcons() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    pref.remove("selectedIcons");
  }

  /// Returns String format of Icons form iconsAsString Map
  /// Throws exception if corresponding String for IconData is not present
  String getStringFormatOfIcon(IconData icon) {
    String? stringFormOfIcon;
    iconsAsString.forEach((key, value) {
      if (value == icon) {
        stringFormOfIcon = key;
      }
    });
    if (stringFormOfIcon == null) {
      throw Exception(
          "String format of Icon not found. Please update the map to include all icons to be displayed");
    }
    return stringFormOfIcon!;
  }

  List<bool> checkValues =
      List.generate(iconsAsString.length, (index) => false);

  void addOrRemoveIconToSharedPrefList(IconData icon) async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    List<String>? previouslySelectedIcons = pref.getStringList("selectedIcons");
    String iconToBeAdded = getStringFormatOfIcon(icon);
    List<String> newSelectedIcons = [];
    if (previouslySelectedIcons != null) {
      /// icons have not been saved yet
      if (previouslySelectedIcons.contains(iconToBeAdded)) {
        previouslySelectedIcons.remove(iconToBeAdded);
        newSelectedIcons = [...previouslySelectedIcons];
      } else {
        /// Since .add method not available in sharedpref
        /// append selected Icon to previous list of selected Icons
        newSelectedIcons = [...previouslySelectedIcons];
        newSelectedIcons.add(iconToBeAdded);
      }
    } else {
      newSelectedIcons.add(iconToBeAdded);
    }
    pref.setStringList("selectedIcons", newSelectedIcons);
    print(newSelectedIcons);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var icons = iconsAsString.values.toList();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Setup Icons for AppBar'),
        actions: [
          FutureBuilder<List<IconData>>(
            future: getSelectedIcons(),
            builder: ((context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                var selectedIcons = snapshot.data!;
                return Row(
                  children: [
                    for (var item in selectedIcons) Icon(item),
                  ],
                );
              } else {
                return const SizedBox();
              }
            }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text('Please select the icons below to include in appbars'),
            Column(
              children: [
                for (int i = 0; i < icons.length; i++)
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        icons[i],
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      Checkbox(
                          value: checkValues[i],
                          activeColor: Colors.green,
                          onChanged: (s) {
                            if (s != null) {
                              setState(() {
                                checkValues[i] = s;
                              });
                              addOrRemoveIconToSharedPrefList(icons[i]);
                            }
                          }),
                    ],
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```